# Single value from json array using nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, rethinkdb

so i have this data which is outputted from `stringify(doc)`

```
{
  "id": "8467fdae-c38c-4b6e-9492-807d7c9eb97e",
  "message": "send to nodejs"
}
```

but im not sure how can i go ahead in getting a single value from it, e.g message. Any help would be appreciated as ive tried different methods and they seem to not be working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you use stringify method the value you have is string.
So You can not get single property from it, except you convert it become object again and get property it. Like this:

```
object = {
  "id": "8467fdae-c38c-4b6e-9492-807d7c9eb97e",
  "message": "send to nodejs"
};

// JSON string is value which you get after use Stringify method
jsonString = JSON.stringify(object);

// Convert jsonString to object again and get message property
message = JSON.parse(jsonString).message
```

Answer (score 0):

`stringify()` will convert `json` to `string`.

Before running `stringify()`, `doc` is already `json` and you can get message by `doc.message`.

after running `stringify()`, the result will be `string`, if you want to get `json` back, you can use `JSON.parse()`